# How the creation of objects on the stack in Qt "function / method" work?

Tags: c++, qt

For example, I have code that I often see:

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QHash *parameterTable;
    explicit ExCurrentSession(QObject *parent = nullptr);
};

SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    parameterTable = new QHash;//used dynamic creation
    QFile file("someFile.txt");//Creating an object on the stack
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    QTextStream fileSream(&file);//Creating an object on the stack
    QString buff = fileSream.readLine();//Creating an object on the stack
    //...Other code to set the QHash table with a parameter and a value from a file...
}
```

The question is whether there will be memory leaks after exiting the method:

-QFile file ? I have no idea what's inside there using dynamic memory, maybe it's not used there.And if it`s using in another subclass inside this class.

-QTextStream fileSream ?I have no idea what's inside object using dynamic memory or not, maybe it's not used there.And if it`s using in another subclass inside this class.

-QString buff?I have no idea what's inside object using dynamic memory or not, maybe it's not used there.

I don’t understand how to determine whether it is possible to use an object on a stack (method / function) if you did not write it yourself and do not 100% sure that dynamic memory allocation is not used there.

Maybe it is more correct? But why often write as in the first version.

```
SomeClass::SomeClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    parameterTable = new QHash;//used dynamic creation
    QFile *file = new QFile("someFile.txt");//Creating an object on the stack
    if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    QTextStream *fileSream = new QTextStream(file);//Creating an object on the stack
    QString *buff = fileSream->readLine();//Creating an object on the stack
    //...Other code to set the QHash table with a parameter and a value from a file...
    delete file;
    delete fileSream;
    delete buff;
}
```

Comment: RAII works in Qt, like it does in standard c++. When the function scope ends all instances are freed and their destructor function are called.

Comment: The general idiom is that an object cleans up its stuff in its destructor. You are not supposed to care about whether internally it uses dynamic allocation or other OS resources - when it is destroyed, it's has freed all its associated data. Local variables are destroyed automatically on scope exit, so you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, I did not know about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "someHash" the destructor is invoked automatically as well?

```
class SomeClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QHash<QString,QString> someHash;
};
```